# How to use rewrite for base url with a declared public folder in firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to configure a web app to use hosting for all static resources, such as jpegs, pngs, etc. But I want to route all requests to a cloud function to monitor traffic for various security reasons.

I managed to achieve this for all routes except the home route using this:

```
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public", //without this everything goes through function, with it the base url is treated like a static get for index.html
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "**",
                "function": "sendWebApp"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is with the home route/base url request. It's ignoring the rewrite for "myurl.com" but uses the rewrite for "myurl.com/whatever-I-type-here". How can I get it to route to the function for the base url as well?

(For clarity.)
EDIT: How can I get firebase hosting not to treat the base url as a static request for index.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Hosting by default will always send index.html from the declared public folder when a request is made to the base URL. The only way to override this is to remove the index.html or don't include the "public" declaration in `firebase.json`'s hosting configuration.

Because [static files ignore the rewrites configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order), you can simplify your rewrites to just:

```json
"hosting": {
  // ... other props ...

  // Serves the function for requests to files or directories that do not exist
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "sendWebApp"
  } ]
}
```

Importantly, if you are accessing a directory of your site, like `/` or `/dashboard/`, the `index.html` in those directories will be served if they exist. This means that your configured rewrite rules will never be checked in these cases.

Comment: I can assure you that this triggered the function for many of my static assets (when no public folder was declared) and still didn't instantiate the function when requesting the base url (with public folder declared).

Comment: @Mr.Drew Please define "with public folder declared". I've used these exact rules in many projects without issue - you just need to ensure that the static paths match exactly (e.g. `example.com/my-static-image.png` would be served by hosting and `example.com/My-Static-Image.png` would be forwarded to the function). Your static assets should be deployed inside whatever folder you are deploying to Firebase hosting. If your static assets are inside your functions folder, consider changing `public` to `functions/static` or `functions/resources` as needed.

Comment: In firebase.json, if I include the line "public": "public" no matter which folder I declare, it routes all requests to that folder for the base url. So `example.com` only loads through hosting, but `example.com/route` loads through the function call as intended.

Comment: As my question states, how can I get the base url to load through the function call and not hosting? I don't have a problem with my static assets being served, just that it's treating my base url `example.com` as a static asset to index.html when I want any call for `example.com` to call my function instead.

Comment: @Mr.Drew If `index.html` exists, remove/rename it.

Comment: I added clarification to your answer. Once it's accepted I can accept it as the official answer. Thanks so much for your help!